# How to give different widths to different columns in entry widget in tkinter based on text length

Tags: python, tkinter

I am fetching data from MS SQL and displaying it in Python using tkinter entry widget for the GUI. However, setting the width in the parameter gives all columns the same width so columns containing ID/Keys have unnecessary space while columns that require more width have their text truncated.

Here is my code:

```
class Table: 
      
    def __init__(self, root, totalRows, totalColoumns, rows): 
          
        # code for creating table 
        for i in range(totalRows): 
            for j in range(totalColoumns): 
                  
                self.e = tkinter.Entry(root, width=50, fg='blue', 
                               font=('Arial', 12)) 
                  
                self.e.grid(row=i, column=j) 
                self.e.insert(tkinter.END, rows[i][j])
```

here the parameters `root`, `totalRows`, `totalColoumns`, `rows` are provided by a function that is calling the above piece of code.

This is the output of all the columns generated where the first two columns are primary key and foreign key:
[image: Output]

Comment: Why don't you use different widths depending on the column instead of using `width=50` everywhere? You could make a list of widths depending in the column number.

Comment: @j_4321 Please do excuse my stupid questions but how do I specify that I want column number 3 to be of width 80 while column 1 and 2 can be of width 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming here that the two first columns can be small, e.g. of width 10, while all the other ones will be larger, e.g. of width 80.

There are plenty of ways to change the for loop creating the table to achieve this. For instance you can create a list of widths:

```
widths = [10, 10] + [80]*(totalColoumns - 2)

# code for creating table 
for i in range(totalRows): 
    for j in range(totalColoumns): 
          
        self.e = tkinter.Entry(root, width=widths[j], fg='blue', 
                       font=('Arial', 12)) 
          
        self.e.grid(row=i, column=j) 
        self.e.insert(tkinter.END, rows[i][j])
```